# Facebook photo gallery widget for my website?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a widget to get all albums and photos from a facebook page and display them in a simple grid on my website?

Preferably, the widget would use PHP, JavaScript, or a combination.

I have a client who wants to display all the pictures found on their facebook business page on their website. I could manually download and upload each picture from facebook to his website, but I figured this would be a good place to use Facebook's api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple widget. Created it in about 3 hours so its not perfect but it works.

There is no CSS styling either so you can easily style it up.

https://github.com/zechdc/Facebook-Photo-Gallery-Widget

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want the page to display images that are currently on the page, so when the photos are updated on the business page the website is also updated?

If so see this below tutorial:

http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html

Looking at the reference to their [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api) it doesn't look to hard, all you need is a photo album id and you can get the photo album as a JSON object:

https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305 (Coca-Cola's wall photos)

Answer (score 1):

You can try SlideshowFx plugin (http://www.oopstouch.com) proposed for Joomla and WordPress.
Initially based on Picasa, they port the plugin to Flickr and Facebook.
A lot of option available.
Check demo here: http://www.oopstouch.com
Regards,
Joël

Answer (score 1):

I use this super duper quick solution. Just replace "{FACEBOOK-PAGE-ID-HERE}" with your facebook page id.

```
<iframe src="http://facebookgalleria.com/gallery.php?id={FACEBOOK-PAGE-ID-HERE}" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" width="551" style="height: 769px;"></iframe>
```